# Choosing the number of colors of a gif in a PHP Script

Tags: php, image, gif

I'm creating a function which will convert images to GIF.

I didn't find any documentation on the PHP website on any function which can limit the number of colors of the outputted gif, can you help me ?

Here's some of the code I'm using :

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($this->_backgroundImage);
header('Content-Type: image/gif');

return imagegif($image);
```

Comment: Why are you limiting the number of colors in an image and **how** do you want to limit the colors?

Comment: The purpose of this development will be to make animated Gifs. And I want these to be as light as possible.

Comment: As for the _how_, I imagine by limiting the available palette ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the function I was looking for : [imagetruecolortopalette](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php)

```
imagetruecolortopalette($image, false, 2);
```